# Rails: undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, math

I am newbie to rails and want to do basic maths in model to get selling price from some maths. I am writing a simple equation in product model. Here is it:

```
 def selling_price
  foodio_price + (foodio_price*@@tax) + @@dc
 end
```

But it is giving error- undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass. It is not recognizing * for multiplication as well as + for sum. Can anybody tell what’s wrong here?

Comment: Where does `foodio_price` come from? Is that a method or an ActiveRecord attribute or something else?

Comment: @muistooshort foodio_price is coming from product form.

Answer (score 3):

One of your variables in that function (like `foodio_price` or `@@tax`) is `nil`. Everything in Ruby is an object, even including `nil`, which you may know in other programming languages as `null`. Every instance of `nil` inherits from the class `NilClass`. Hence, `nil:NilClass` is referring to an instance of `nil` which is of type `NilClass`.

To debug this issue you can check which (or al three) of these values is `nil` by adding `puts` statements.

---

My guess is that both `@@tax` and `@@dc` are `nil`. Rarely do you need to use these class variables in Rails. I'd suggest just declaring the `tax` and `dc` as constants, so something like

```
TAX = 0.09
DC = 0.10
```

somewhere in your class file.

---

For default values on a `nil` parameter for `foodio_price`

```
def selling_price foodio_price
  if foodio_price.nil? return 0.0
  foodio_price + (foodio_price*@@tax) + @@dc
end
```

Comment: yeah, you are right. Foodioprice is nil. I have defined the tax and dc. But as Foodio_price the input from user, it will be nil. how to do this then?

Comment: If `foodio_price` is nil, do something like what my edit suggests.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying the foodio_price is an object from NilClass class

In pseudo code, foodio_price = nil

Your variable foodio_price is not instancied (don't have any value yet)

You should try this

```
def selling_price(foodio_price)
  foodio_price + (foodio_price*@@tax) + @@dc
end
```

And in other places of your code, where you call the function `selling_price`, you pass it the parameter `foodio_price`

Answer (score 0):

it worked. Changed my model to:

```
 def selling_price
  self.foodio_price  ||= 0.0  
  foodio_price + (foodio_price*@@tax) + @@dc
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foodio_price + ((foodio_price || 1)*(@@tax || 1|) + (@@dc || 0)
```

Try this